# Convert Some JSON Keys to Python Object

Tags: python, json

I have a Python class that looks like the below:

```
class Game:
    """Holds all game related attributes - usually one instance created per game."""

    def __init__(
        self,
        game_id,
        game_type,
        date_time,
        game_state,
        venue,
        home,
        away,
        preferred,
        live_feed,
        season,
    ):

        self.game_id = game_id
        self.game_type = game_type
        self.date_time = date_time
        self.game_state = game_state
        self.venue = venue
        self._live_feed = live_feed
        self.home_team = home
        self.away_team = away
        self.season = season
```

Currently I create an instance of this class by parsing JSON from a API response and cherry-picking some values and passing those into the `init()` function of this class.

Is it better (so all logic around this class is in one place) to just pass the API response into the `init()` function and do the parsing / cherry-picking of those attributes from that JSON dictionary in the class to set the class-level attributes?

For example, I grab these values in my `main()` function and then pass them into the class.

```
# Create a Game Object
    gameobj_game_id = game_info["gamePk"]
    gameobj_game_season = game_info["season"]
    gameobj_game_type = game_info["gameType"]
    gameobj_date_time = game_info["gameDate"]
    gameobj_game_state = game_info["status"]["abstractGameState"]

game_obj = Game(gameobj_game_id, gameobj_game_type, gameobj_date_time, gameobj_game_state...)
```

But that code is abstracted away from the object creation logic.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I would cherry pick (though I would do it with dictionary comprehension). You may also want to consider keyword unpacking via `game_obj = Game(**my_params_in_a_dict)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to define a class method whose job it is to extra the "right" fields from such a response.

```
class Game:
    """Holds all game related attributes - usually one instance created per game."""

    def __init__(
        self,
        game_id,
        game_type,
        date_time,
        game_state,
        venue,
        home,
        away,
        preferred,
        live_feed,
        season,
    ):

        self.game_id = game_id
        self.game_type = game_type
        self.date_time = date_time
        self.game_state = game_state
        self.venue = venue
        self._live_feed = live_feed
        self.home_team = home
        self.away_team = away
        self.season = season

    @classmethod
    def from_json(cls, resp):
        return Game(
            game_id=resp["gamePk"],
            game_type=resp["gameType"],
            ...
        )
```

The type itself is the "method" (in that `Game(...)` is indirectly equivalent to `Game.__new__(...)`) that provides the canonical way of creating an object, being agnostic as to where each bit of information comes from. Additional class methods act as wrappers around various sources for the same data.